# Почему телебот не может отправить фото в телеграм боте?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Не отправляется приветственная картинка в телеграм боте, появляется ошибка. Хотя `bot.send_message` работает .Но когда отправляю фото , пишет таймаут

Вот отрывок кода:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
        keyboardmain = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        first_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Еда", callback_data="first") 
        #Кнопка главного меню
        keyboardmain.add(first_button)
        photo = open('photo/main.jpg', 'rb')
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo, caption="Добро пожаловать в наш 
        региональный бот, выберите , что вас интересует?", reply_markup=keyboardmain)
```

Comment: Можете ли вы скинуть фото ошибки? Например скрин где видно как ваш бот отреагировал.

Comment: куда и как скинуть?

Comment: как вам удобно? Куда-то выложите фотку и дайте ссылку

Comment: https://ibb.co/PMggxRh

Comment: Пожайлуста вставьте весь код в свой вопрос, тут непонятно из-за чего это возникает, и  не забудьте убрать токен.

Comment: https://ibb.co/PmcFp87 скину так , чтобы аккуратно было все

Comment: замените это `bot.polling()` на это `bot.polling(none_stop=True,interval=0 )`

Comment: то же самое получается

Comment: Ну не знаю, эта ошибка не в коде. Наверное либо у вас интернет плохой либо ещё что-то

Comment: может для фото какой-то отдельный модуль нужен? как для телебота pytelebotapi&

Comment: Нет, дело в том что у меня всё работает прекрасно

Comment: Наверное в вашем регионе запретили Telegram. Попробуй включить VPN и попробуйте ещё раз.

Comment: дело только в картинке. Обычное приветственное сообщение пробовал, все работает,не может же только на картинку распространяться

Comment: Ну возможно какая-то картинка плохая, поменяй ее на другую)

Comment: Вы отправляете объект а не байты фото

Comment: кстати так и есть) не ожидал , но решил все таки проверить точно и заработало!

Comment: photo.read()---;-)